# Sending a null terminating character over a socket in c

Tags: c, sockets, null

I'm trying to send a string with a null terminating character inside of it to another connection.

Now I'm not dumb, I know a string will stop at that character, but is there any possible way to send a string to a socket like this, "Test\x00AFTERNULL\x00\r\n".

I was thinking maybe there's a way to convert it from one encoding to another or something. I'm not exactly smart in this area. Thanks for any help/input.

Comment: Which OS? The socket functions I know don't operate on strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending over socket is not related to having null in middle of string or not, because `send()` will send a buffer with specific size.

This buffer can have any amount of zeroes in middle of it. You probably have used `strlen()` to get size of string and used it in `send()` which result in incorrect buffer length and missing some part of data.

You can do it like this for example (very simple one):

```
char buf[] = "Test\0AFTERNULL\0\r\n";
//'s' is socket descriptor
send(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
```

Comment: In that simple example, you'd probably want to use `sizeof(buf) - 1` for the length unless you want to include the null terminator after the `'\n'`.

Comment: @IanAbbott While I agree the OP also stated the string to send also **in double quotes**, so he might want to include the trailing null byte in the message.

Comment: Didn't work when I used the hex \x00, but it worked when I replaced it with ascii \0. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Send and receive data via socket use byte array, not string. 
Exampe: create array: {'T', 'E', 'S','T', 0, 'A'}, send this via socket with leng is 6. And the other socket will received same array

Comment: In C, there's no `byte` type and `typeof('V') == int`. And what is `leng`?

Comment: Byte mean char or unsigned char (because size of it is 1 byte). Typeof 'V' is char. Length mean number of bytes that you want to send via socket

Comment: @cad, In C, a byte is the smallest unit of addressable storage.

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm well aware of that. Still, he might consider replacing "byte" with `char` for clarity's sake and perform some other changes to improve his post. Or do you consider the answer good?